# using hangfire schedule with unique id

Tags: hangfire

i am using hangFire to notify user about his today meeting. here is my code in application startup or in some other method that run periodically

```
TimeSpan timeSpan = DateTime.Now- notificationTime ;
BackgroundJob.Schedule(() => sendNotification(reminder.Meeting_Id), timeSpan);
```

the problem is whenever user visit my the webiste a new scheduled item is added to hangfire .

how can i set Hangfire to run scheduled item in specific time and give this schedule a unique id ?

Answer (score 0):

You can queue something to happen at a specific time rather than after a delay, you just need to pass in the time you want the Job to be enqueued:

```
String uniqueJobId = BackgroundJob.Schedule(() => Console.WriteLine("Task"), notificationTime);
```

The Schedule method also returns a String Id of the Job so you can reference it later if required.

Bear in mind that your job will be enqueued at this time, which may cause a wait for it to be executed depending on the status of your queue and whether a server is available to process it. Not much you can do about this except make sure you have enough capacity to keep your queue length down.